# javascript detect device and render mobile view or web view

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, navigator

I'm using react library to render my application on client side. 
But I need two separate views to render.

1. Small device `width < 600px`
2. Larger device `width > 600px`

What is the right way to detect the browser along with its width and render the application accordingly?

I have no idea whether the server responds with a different view or it will be handled on the client side.

Comment: Why separate views? Why not do it in css with media queries?

Comment: Actually, I need separate view for mobile users with slow internet connections.